# Evaluate image in html table using Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to parse a table and save it into a csv file. However, some of the cells are images (*.gif) of a checkmark and I am unsure how to evaluate when exporting to csv.

here is some html code:

```
<BODY>
<TABLE>
<TH>
<H3>    <BR>TABLE 1    </H3> 
</TH>
<TR>
<TD>Data 1    </TD>
<TD>Data 2    </TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>example.gif    </TD>
<TD>example.gif   </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
```

In the actual table, the html for the table row that includes the .gif is

```
<td align="center" width="55px">
<!--
-->
<img align="top" height="13" hspace="2" src="http://explorer.natureserve.org/images/checkmark.gif" vspace="2" width="14"/>
<!--
-->
</td>
```

The code I have so far is:

```
table = soup.find('table')
rows = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    rows.append([val.text.encode('utf8') for val in row.find_all('td')])
```

In the example provide, the code I have evaluates to:

```
[
    'Spartina patens', 
    'G5', 
    'Graminoid',
    'Herb (field)', 
    '\n\r\n                        \xc2\xa0\r\n\n', 
    '\n\n\n\n', 
    '\n\r\n                       \xc2\xa0\r\n\n', 
    '\xc2\xa0', 
    '\xc2\xa0'
 ]
```

I am guessing that if the cell doesn't include '\xc2\x', then I could evaluate to a 1, but not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

What I would like to do is place a 1 in the appropriate row and column if the image is present and a 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there is `img` for every `td` in the loop:

```
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    rows.append([1 if val.img else 0 for val in row.find_all('td')])
```

Or a bit trickier:

```
[int(val.img is not None) for val in row.find_all('td')]
```

where `val.img` is a shortcut to `val.find('img')`.

Comment: That works great. Unfortunately, I only need to evaluate the 4 through 9 columns in the table. How would I do that? I have written some klugey code but am ashamed to share it.

Comment: @user44796 just slice it: `row.find_all('td')[3:9]`.